# versioning in NetCore 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, version

good morning

I have my API and I want to make two versions of it, reading this excellent post (https://dev.to/htissink/versioning-asp-net-core-apis-with-swashbuckle-making-space-potatoes-v-x-x-x-3po7) .
I follow every step to the letter, and I have the error I attached ...

*** ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: v1
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API 1 HILP", Version = "v1" }); ***

(this is a small piece of the code) ... :

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API 1 HILP", Version = "v1" });
            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Info { Title = "API 2 *PRUEBA* HILP", Version = "v2" });
           // c.ExampleFilters();


            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
        });
```

From what I understand, I am using the same Key twice but I cannot find this error.

I appreciate every contribution and help!

Regards!!

Comment: That's a dead link. If you exclude `c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);` do you get the error?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!
 the link ....
https://dev.to/htissink/versioning-asp-net-core-apis-with-swashbuckle-making-space-potatoes-v-x-x-x-3po7

"c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName); do you get the error?" yes, dosn't change

Comment: It looks like you did not follow the guide completely, one of the first lines: 'Disclaimer: due to bugs in ASP.Net Core 2.2.0, please use ASP.Net Core 2.1.0'

Comment: Thamk you @LinkedListT , i gonna fix this....
And try again...Once more, thank you!